# Hide empty parent folders QTreeView/QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, treeview, qfilesystemmodel

So i have a tree viewas shown below;

```
    #QTreeView widget
    #Shows files in set directory
    self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralWidget)
    self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.treeView)
    self.file_model=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    self.file_model.setRootPath('C:\My Stuff\Movies')
    self.treeView.setModel(self.file_model)
    self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.file_model.index('C:\My Stuff\Movies'))
    self.treeView.setColumnWidth(0,275)
    self.file_model.setNameFilters(self.filterList)
    self.file_model.setNameFilterDisables(0)
```

As you can see i have a filter that hides items that dont pass the filter (e.g. *.mkv) however i have folders in my directory that contain a file that does not fit the filter requirements. The folder remains in my treeview even though it is empty, how do i remove these empty folders (Keep in mind i need to be able to show these folders when i apply a filter that allows for the file in the folder to be shown.

I am running PyQt5, Python 3.5, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same question and this is the way I tried to solve the problem.

You need to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and override the `hasChildren` and `filterAcceptsRow`.

Please take note that instead of calling the `QFileSystemModel`'s `setNameFilters` you would need to call the subclassed `QSortFilterProxyModel`'s `nameFilters` method.

**This is the code I ended up basing on the implementation above:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class DirProxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    nameFilters = ''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.dirModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs | QDir.Files) # <- added QDir.Files to view all files
        self.setSourceModel(self.dirModel)

    def setNameFilters(self, filters):
        if not isinstance(filters, (tuple, list)):
            filters = [filters]
        self.nameFilters = filters
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def hasChildren(self, parent):
        sourceParent = self.mapToSource(parent)
        if not self.dirModel.hasChildren(sourceParent):
            return False
        qdir = QDir(self.dirModel.filePath(sourceParent))
        return bool(qdir.entryInfoList(qdir.NoDotAndDotDot|qdir.AllEntries|qdir.AllDirs))
    
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        source = self.dirModel.index(row, 0, parent)
        if source.isValid():
            if self.dirModel.isDir(source):
                qdir = QDir(self.dirModel.filePath(source))
                if self.nameFilters:
                    qdir.setNameFilters(self.nameFilters)
                return bool(qdir.entryInfoList(qdir.NoDotAndDotDot|qdir.AllEntries|qdir.AllDirs))

            elif self.nameFilters:  # <- index refers to a file
                qdir = QDir(self.dirModel.filePath(source))
                return qdir.match(self.nameFilters, self.dirModel.fileName(source)) # <- returns true if the file matches the nameFilters
        return True

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.dirProxy = DirProxy()
        self.dirProxy.dirModel.directoryLoaded.connect(lambda : self.treeView.expandAll())
        self.dirProxy.setNameFilters(['*.ai'])  # <- filtering all files and folders with "*.ai"
        self.dirProxy.dirModel.setRootPath(r"<Dir>")

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.dirProxy)

        root_index = self.dirProxy.dirModel.index(r"<Dir>")
        proxy_index = self.dirProxy.mapFromSource(root_index)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(proxy_index)

        self.treeView.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**This is the testing I did and the result looks just fine to me:**

Trial 1:
[image]

Trial 2:
[image]

Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63669844/15870976) for more info.